# unable to parse json object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to iterate each element of json but fails to print.
i tired JSON.parse() too.

**code:**

```
var j = "{\"Type\": \"INFO \",\"TimeStamp\":\"2018-10-10 12:05:16.881\",\"IP\":\"2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a\",\"MacId\":\"84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4\",\"OS\":\"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language\",\"Method\":\"SyncData\",\"LineNo\":527,\"Message\":\"SyncData: Billing Software SyncData() called\"}\r\n{\"Type\": \"INFO \",\"TimeStamp\":\"2018-10-10 12:05:17.060\",\"IP\":\"2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a\",\"MacId\":\"84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4\",\"OS\":\"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language\",\"Method\":\"SyncData\",\"LineNo\":38,\"Message\":\"SyncData: Start\"}\r\n{\"Type\": \"INFO \",\"TimeStamp\":\"2018-10-10 12:05:17.111\",\"IP\":\"2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a\",\"MacId\":\"84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4\",\"OS\":\"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language\",\"Method\":\"SyncData\",\"LineNo\":44,\"Message\":\"SyncData: LocalConnectionString = Data Source=PARAM\\\\MSSQL2K8r2;Initial Catalog=HQPharma;User ID=sa;Password=developer;\"}";  
for(var key in j){
    console.log(j[key]);
}
```

above code prints each character like 
[image]

Comment: It's the classical confusion between the JSON data format and JavaScript objects. You have a **string** and you never parse it as JSON so you're just looping its characters.

Comment: What @ÁlvaroGonzález said is true, plus after you used `JSON.parse()` you most likely want to loop on `Object.keys(j)`, not on `j` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I noticed when I formatted your string was this

```
{
 "Type": "INFO ",
  "TimeStamp": "2018-10-10 12:05:16.881",
  "IP": "2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a",
  "MacId": "84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4",
  "OS": "Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language",
  "Method": "SyncData",
  "LineNo": 527,
  "Message": "SyncData: Billing Software SyncData() called"
}\n{
  "Type": "INFO ",
  "TimeStamp": "2018-10-10 12:05:17.060",
  "IP": "2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a",
  "MacId": "84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4",
  "OS": "Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language",
  "Method": "SyncData",
  "LineNo": 38,
  "Message": "SyncData: Start"
}\n{
  "Type": "INFO ",
  "TimeStamp": "2018-10-10 12:05:17.111",
  "IP": "2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a",
  "MacId": "84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4",
  "OS": "Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language",
  "Method": "SyncData",
  "LineNo": 44,
  "Message": "SyncData: LocalConnectionString = Data Source=PARAM\\MSSQL2K8r2;Initial Catalog=HQPharma;User ID=sa;Password=developer;"
}
```

To work with this you can do something like this

```js
const j = "{\"Type\": \"INFO \",\"TimeStamp\":\"2018-10-10 12:05:16.881\",\"IP\":\"2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a\",\"MacId\":\"84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4\",\"OS\":\"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language\",\"Method\":\"SyncData\",\"LineNo\":527,\"Message\":\"SyncData: Billing Software SyncData() called\"}\r\n{\"Type\": \"INFO \",\"TimeStamp\":\"2018-10-10 12:05:17.060\",\"IP\":\"2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a\",\"MacId\":\"84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4\",\"OS\":\"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language\",\"Method\":\"SyncData\",\"LineNo\":38,\"Message\":\"SyncData: Start\"}\r\n{\"Type\": \"INFO \",\"TimeStamp\":\"2018-10-10 12:05:17.111\",\"IP\":\"2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a\",\"MacId\":\"84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4\",\"OS\":\"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language\",\"Method\":\"SyncData\",\"LineNo\":44,\"Message\":\"SyncData: LocalConnectionString = Data Source=PARAM\\\\MSSQL2K8r2;Initial Catalog=HQPharma;User ID=sa;Password=developer;\"}";  

//first remove the \n and join with a comma ,
// enclose your multiple object within an array
const joinedWithComma = "[" + j.split('\n').join(',') + "]"


//now parse this
const parsedValue = JSON.parse(joinedWithComma)


console.log(parsedValue)
```

Comment: Even when the OP has marked your answer as the solution, it's not. OP was trying to iterate properties from a string, and your answer says nothing about this. Both the other one and mine does it already...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer well I figured out that once the string was parsed, the OP would be able to iterate over it ?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer and I also believe that the question states that the OP needs to parse the string:- "unable to parse json object"

Comment: I don't think so. I really believe the OP wanted a solution to avoid putting his own effort... The problem explained in the whole question is about confusing a string with an object, and also - but just a detail - the JSON was invalid. I don't expect someone to ask to turn us into a human JSON linter, anyway :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer the string presented seems like a response sort of string; from an API call or from other sources. The title of the question as well as mentioning failed `JSON.parse()`, I could only infer that the OP might be asking for a way to parse these 'type' of strings.

Comment: What happens if you have a property like `"Message": "SyncData: LocalConnectionString = Data Source=PARAM\\MSSQL2K8r2;Initial Catalog=HQPharma;User ID=sa;Password=developer;\nThis is just a string message"`?

Comment: @ChatterOne it would not work. The presented solution only works for the presented problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should parse the string and convert to a JSON object using the method [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

**EDIT**

I noticed that your string has several JSON objects, so you should split the string by `\r\n` before passing to `JSON.parse` method.

```
var j = "{\"Type\": \"INFO \",\"TimeStamp\":\"2018-10-10 12:05:16.881\",\"IP\":\"2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a\",\"MacId\":\"84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4\",\"OS\":\"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language\",\"Method\":\"SyncData\",\"LineNo\":527,\"Message\":\"SyncData: Billing Software SyncData() called\"}\r\n{\"Type\": \"INFO \",\"TimeStamp\":\"2018-10-10 12:05:17.060\",\"IP\":\"2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a\",\"MacId\":\"84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4\",\"OS\":\"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language\",\"Method\":\"SyncData\",\"LineNo\":38,\"Message\":\"SyncData: Start\"}\r\n{\"Type\": \"INFO \",\"TimeStamp\":\"2018-10-10 12:05:17.111\",\"IP\":\"2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a\",\"MacId\":\"84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4\",\"OS\":\"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language\",\"Method\":\"SyncData\",\"LineNo\":44,\"Message\":\"SyncData: LocalConnectionString = Data Source=PARAM\\\\MSSQL2K8r2;Initial Catalog=HQPharma;User ID=sa;Password=developer;\"}";
var list = j.split('\r\n');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(list[i]);
  for(var key in obj) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data on line 10

Comment: Like Matias said in its answer, the JSON you provided is not valid. I didn't check that. That's the reason for the error.

Comment: It's not valid and it's not an object, but an array of objects! :D

Comment: Yeah, forgot to change the log of `j[key]` to `obj[key]`. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you're iterating characters of a given string. That string is in JSON format, but it's still an array of characters.

Also, your JSON isn't valid. After cleaning it up, I've noticed that it's a JSON array of JSON objects:

```js
const os = JSON.parse(`[{
  "Type": "INFO ",
  "TimeStamp": "2018-10-10 12:05:16.881",
  "IP": "2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a",
  "MacId": "84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4",
  "OS": "Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language",
  "Method": "SyncData",
  "LineNo": 527,
  "Message": "SyncData: Billing Software SyncData() called"
 },
 {
  "Type": "INFO ",
  "TimeStamp": "2018-10-10 12:05:17.060",
  "IP": "2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a",
  "MacId": "84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4",
  "OS": "Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language",
  "Method": "SyncData",
  "LineNo": 38,
  "Message": "SyncData: Start"
 },
 {
  "Type": "INFO ",
  "TimeStamp": "2018-10-10 12:05:17.111",
  "IP": "2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a",
  "MacId": "84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4",
  "OS": "Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language",
  "Method": "SyncData",
  "LineNo": 44,
  "Message": "SyncData: LocalConnectionString = Data Source=PARAM\\\\MSSQL2K8r2;Initial Catalog=HQPharma;User ID=sa;Password=developer;"
 }
]`)


for (let o of os)
  for (let key in o)
    console.log(key, ' = ', o[key])
```

Comment: @JunedAnsari There's no by to autofix it :D I've fixed it by hand, there's no other way to do it.

Comment: @JunedAnsari Clarification: as some other answer points out, when I've said *no autofix* I mean that you need to implement the fix yourself. In my case, for the sake of answering you, I fixed it manually. Anyway, I believe that fixing JSON is out of the scope of your question.